# CSS namespacing and overriding jquery selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm looking to override the base jQuery selector so that all CSS classes ( `$('.classname')` ) in any jQuery selector, including `.find(.classname)`, `.parents(.classname)`, etc, are prefixed with a 'namespace'.  In the above example my jQuery code would look like, `$('.classname')`, but that would be translated to `$('.SomeCssNamespace_classname')`.

The HTML that the `$('.classname')` selector would match would look like this:
    `<div class="SomeCssNamespace_classname" />`

Most importantly is that I would have to add the smarts, maybe in the form of a `regex`, that would only do this for classnames, not id's or tag selectors.  e.g. `$('#someId')` would not be translated to `$('#SomeCssNamespace_someId')`.

Additionally, the `jQuery.addClass()` and `jQuery.removeClass()` methods would have to be overridden to prepend the same namespace.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Lian: I think OP wants to know how you can extend the jQuery default selector behaviour when specifying class selectors, so that jQuery accepts `$('.className')` but is able to match that selector to an element with `class="namespace_className"` instead/or as well as (not sure about that) `class="className"`. Bascially having jQuery automatically pre-pend `namespace_` to match the selector. In addition OP want that behaviour replicated in any method using class names as input, such as `addClass` or `removeClass` for example. I asusme that is what OP is looking for.

Comment: Unless I'm not seeing something I think your best bet would be to download the version of the jQuery file you want to use and update it directly in the source and use your own customised copy of it.

Comment: [CSS namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace) are something completely different from what you have here.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yes you have a firm grasp on the question.  To clarify <div class="className"> does not need to be supported.  I would like to stay away from editing the jQ source if possible, but realize that might be necessary.  Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to write your own functions to do this... for example:

```
prefixClassSelector = function(prefix,class_name) {
    return $('.' + prefix + '_' + class_name);
}
```

then you can call it like this, and it's still chainable

```
prefixClassSelector('someNamespace','myclass').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for our suggestion, however i have a lot of code that I am trying to avoid re-writing by overriding or extending the jQ selector function.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// define the namespace
jQuery.myjQueryNamespace = {

  name: 'custom_', // the prefix

  // returns the prefixed selector, classname needs to be prefixed with "."
  addNamespace: function(selector) {

    if (typeof String.prototype.indexOf == "function") {
      return selector.replace(/\./g, '.' + jQuery.myjQueryNamespace.name);
    } else {
      // TODO: write my own indexOf function
      return selector;
    }
  },

  // returns the prefixed selector, classname should *not* to be prefixed with "."
  prefixNamespace: function(selector) {
    return jQuery.myjQueryNamespace.name + 'selector';
  }
}

// keep the original init function
jQuery.fn._init = jQuery.fn.init;

jQuery.fn.init = function(selector, context, rootjQuery) {

  if (typeof selector == 'string'
  && typeof String.prototype.indexOf == "function" // assumes String.prototype.indexOf is defined
  && selector.indexOf('.') != -1) {

    var myNewSelector = jQuery.myjQueryNamespace.addNamespace(selector);
    return jQuery.fn._init.call(this, myNewSelector, context, rootjQuery);
  } else {

    return jQuery.fn._init.call(this, selector, context, rootjQuery)
  }
}

// *got this from the jQuery source code
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;

// modify addClass and removeClass
for (var fn_key in jQuery.fn) {

  // if the function has "Class" in it, replace the function
  if (fn_key == 'addClass' || fn_key == 'removeClass') {

    // we'll keep the original function prefixed with underscore
    jQuery.fn['_' + fn_key] = jQuery.fn[fn_key];

    // build the new function which calls the original function passing in the namespaced selector
    var new_function = new Function("selector", "return jQuery.fn['" + '_' + fn_key + "'].call(this, jQuery.myjQueryNamespace.prefixNamespace(selector));");

    // assign it to the original name
    jQuery.fn[fn_key] = new_function;
  }
}
```

Warning: I have only tested this by pasting into the console, and only in chrome. It may have unexpected behaviors.

It would be best to run this right after you load jquery, allowing other plugins to be namespaced.

What the code does is it replaces the `jQuery.fn.init` function with a modified version that prefixes class names. The `jQuery.fn.init` function runs when you call `$(selector)`. We modify `addClass` and `removeClass` in a similar way.